# Would Obama viewing Trump's tax returns be seen as overstepping his authority?

Tags: united-states, president, taxes, public-opinion

[26 U.S. Code § 6103(g)(1)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/6103) says that the President can request tax return information from the IRS:

> Upon written request by the President, signed by him personally, the Secretary shall furnish to the President, or to such employee or employees of the White House Office as the President may designate by name in such request, a return or return information with respect to any taxpayer named in such request.

This request, if made now, would have to be disclosed to Congress by Jan. 30, 2017 [by which point the election will (likely) be over and the next President inaugurated]:

> Within 30 days after the close of each calendar quarter, the President... shall file a report with the Joint Committee on Taxation setting forth the taxpayers with respect to whom such requests were made during such quarter under this subsection, the returns or return information involved, and the reasons for such requests.

(A reason must be stated, but there are no clear additional requirements on what that reason may be).

[§6103(a)(1) of the same title](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/6103) establishes the general rule that:

> Returns and return information shall be confidential, and except as authorized by this title, no officer or employee of the United States
> shall disclose any return or return information obtained by him in any manner in connection with his service as such an officer or an employee or otherwise or under the provisions of this section. For purposes of this subsection, the term “officer or employee” includes a former officer or employee.

So it seems that Obama would not be able to directly share what he learns with the electorate, but merely disclosing that he has accessed the returns and after looking at them, really doesn't think Trump is in a competent position to take the office, might give more weight to what he's saying in at least some voters' eyes.  Obama even publicizing that the option is there, with the implication he might use it, might add pressure for Trump to release returns voluntarily (limiting folks' imaginations), especially once the surprise factor of $0 paid (if that's accurate) has been absorbed.

Trump seems to be very willing to use executive authority to override treaties, international laws, etc. and thinks it's "smart" to gain maximal personal benefit from the laws in place in the tax code, so he'd seem to have a hard time challenging the ethics of Obama *also* using the existing tax laws to get the access the laws expressly permit him to have.

Trump famously pressed Obama for the release of his long-form birth certificate and still seems to think he deserves credit for getting to be able to see that, so Obama having a look at Trump's tax returns might be seen as at least partially a response which he can accomplish relatively easily from his current elected position.

Is there any polling, history, or other evidence indicating how the electorate would likely react to such a move?

Comment: I think this is going to be mostly opinion unless there is a poll out there already asking this hypothetical question. But even then, it's such a hypothetical that I imagine *how* the question is asked can also vary wildly producing very different polling data.

Comment: Your idea about `Obama [...] disclosing that he has accessed the returns [...] really doesn't think Trump is in a competent position` would be a breach of confidentality similar to directly publishing the data. To put an analogy, a doctor is not only forbidden of disclosing someone's medical condition but cannot either tell (publicly) something like "By the way, Mr. X, there is a new treatment which is **really** effective at healing ghonorrea, after seeing the results of your last analysis I relally think you should give it a try".

Comment: And yes, regardless of whether the law allows, Obama asking to see Trump's returns would be seen as greatly overstepping of his authority, as there is no legitimate thing he can do with those (and no, deciding which candidates are worthy and which are not is not the President job in any democratic country). Maybe if he were to enter the IRS after his term expires...

Comment: @SJuan76 That kind of comment is too specific; it's not a good analogy.  Obama could continue to make exactly the same kinds of general comments he has already been making about which candidates are and aren't worthy, unchanged, but people might give extra weight to it if they know it's even more informed.

Comment: This could be answered with historical references if any exist.

Comment: No, and nobody really cares. Different with the orchestrated surveillance.

Answer (score -9):

The quest to see Trump's tax returns is nothing but political theatre. The only reason anyone would want to see them is to confirm whether there is any illegal activity or not.
However it's not Obama's job to investigate or prosecute any individual's taxation activity; that is the job of the IRS.
If Trump had been involved in ANY illegal activity with regards to his taxes, the IRS most certainly would've acted by now.
Recall that Al Capone was brought down by the IRS.

How the electorate would react to Obama using his contacts and position to acquire Trump's tax returns should be self-evident. Anyone who supports Obama would celebrate the move. Anyone who supports Trump would not.

Source: common sense.

Comment: And yet every presidential candidate since the 60s has released their own tax returns and Trump promised to do so on multiple occasion. Rather than theatre, the real issue is honesty and integrity.

Comment: Rather than theatre, the real issue is honesty and integrity. Which is why it is unlikely that Obama or now Biden would make such a move, or that it would get the full backing you suggest, as it would shift the focus from Trump's integrity to their own. Tax is a difficult issue, which is why tax enforcement agencies focus on the little people, and not the financial arrangements of [millionaire businesses](https://www.taxwatchuk.org/https://www.taxwatchuk.org/tax_crime_vs_benefits_crime).

Comment: @Jontia I wouldn't care if every human on earth released their tax returns and Trump didn't, as long as the IRS hasn't detected illegal activity, its no one else's business.
And the core reason for wanting to see tax returns would be to see if there is in fact evidence of illegal activity.
Since we can safely assume there is no illegal activity to be found, then it becomes clear that the only reason to request it is for Trumps adversaries to pick apart every business decision he has ever made and armchair quarterback it. The goal being of course to try and destroy his reputation.

Comment: if that's how you feel then that is fine. I'd even agree with the stance if Trump himself hadn't promised to release them. That makes it about his dishonesty rather than anything in the content. And we can't assume there's nothing illegal given the number of investigations (is the 2016 it's audit still going too?) currently running.

Comment: The NYT released some information that Trump didn't pay income tax or very little and they framed that as evidence of wrongdoing. However, Jeff Bezos, Elon Musk and many other incredibly rich people also have avoided paying income tax many times and they all do it legally. They are working within the laws.

You may have a moral or ethical judgment about that but if you think Trump has done the wrong thing, then your problem is with the system, not him.

https://www.usatoday.com/story/money/2021/06/10/propublica-tax-leak-irs-files-show-how-billionaires-pay-low-tax/7639768002/

Comment: True, besides I doubt Trump or any rich individual do their own taxes. They probably pay a team of accountants to do it for them so it's highly unlikely they would be doing something illegal.

Comment: @Ray Exactly, even IF the IRS or anyone else actually found any illegal activity, Trump wouldn't bear the responsibility for it, would be his financial services team. And rightfully so. If I had so many business interests that required a full time accounting services team to administer, the legitimate expectation is that they do not break the law.

Comment: Tax returns can serve as evidence of crimes that have nothing to do with the tax code, so it is not only the IRS's job to investigate people's tax returns.  The Department of Justice also has a reason to examine them - - which they are presently doing.  The fact that it's possible for a rich person to pay very little tax legally does not imply that Trump's tax returns are clean.  And a taxpayer absolutely has liability for fraud in the return even if it was prepared by someone else.  Trump has built his entire life on lies; the idea that his tax returns are honest is difficult to believe.

Comment: @Ray lots of people who file fraudulent tax returns have paid accountants to prepare them.  This is possible because the taxpayer can provide false information to the accountant or the accountant can also be a criminal.  But the most likely reason for Trump's reluctance to disclose the returns is that they would show that he isn't nearly as rich as he claims.  His public persona is one big bluff.

Comment: @phoog To be fair, every politician, every celebrity and even YOU has a public persona. If I ask you to post your tax returns on here for all of us to see, would you?

Comment: @NetServOps of course not. I am not a public servant, and I never promised anyone that I would release my tax returns.  My point isn't that having a public persona implies an obligation to release tax returns but that Trump has demonstrated with remarkable consistency since the 1960s that dishonesty is a central element of his character, from [claiming his buildings are taller than they really are](https://www.nytimes.com/2016/11/02/nyregion/donald-trump-tower-heights.html) to [golf](https://golf.com/lifestyle/celebrities/how-why-president-trump-cheats-golf-playing-tiger-woods/) to bone spurs.

Comment: @phoog  He did promise he would release his tax returns and he will however, he is currently under an audit which was started in 2011. 
The point is, even IF he didn't say he would release his tax returns, you would still demand to see them on the basis that most other presidents before him have.
Remember, Gerald Ford didn't release his full tax return information and this 'tradition' of releasing them only began in the 70s so it hasn't been every single president.
And, you're forgetting that personal income tax is private and you are not legally compelled to disclose details to the public.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126400/discussion-between-phoog-and-netservops).

Comment: "as long as the IRS hasn't detected illegal activity, its no one else's business. And the core reason for wanting to see tax returns would be to see if there is in fact evidence of illegal activity." I respectfully disagree. I think that people who seek roles where they will have a huge influence on determining exactly what the national tax policy & rules are, those who making a decision about whether to give them that role should be able to know how they use the status quo system, to better understand the individual's personal financial incentives for arguing for/against particular changes.

Comment: Plus, appointees & civil servants have to provide this kind of information when applying for a position requiring a security clearance, for the purposes of understanding financial influences and what foreign powers might hold significant influence on the person’s financial life. The President gets a very high level clearance & the public is the hiring committee; they should be able to understand this sort of influence.

Comment: @WBT You say that kind of info is required for a security clearance, of course it is, but that info is given only to the department or agency whose job it is to grant the clearance, its not for the public and its 'need to know'. You make the point that in the context of a Presidency, that the public is the 'hiring committee' and therefore, they should be privy to all tax related info for that individual as it could reveal their motives for making certain tax rule decisions etc. The issue I have with this is that the general public is not educated enough to make such a determination.

Comment: @WBT To continue, the general public is not educated enough to understand the complexities of the taxation system and therefore, they should not be handed such information about a persons tax related activities. Do you really think the average joe would understand the laws and rules around all the business activities Trump has engaged in? Would a truck driver even begin to understand billionaire business deals? I don't think so. This is why we have the IRS, they essentially police the taxation system and if there is any wrongdoing, they will find it if its there.

Comment: @WBT So, releasing the taxation information to the general public would serve no purpose for Trump, but it would certainly serve his opponents as they pour over every detail of his business history and look to generate story after story of negative press. Even if Trump hasn't done anything illegal, its easy to make businessmen look bad from a moral or ethical standpoint, and this is what his enemies would try. It wouldn't work on me because I believe business is business, its not personal. As long as you act in accordance with the law and within the taxation framework, then you're ok.

Comment: @NetServOps maybe your opinion wouldn't be affected, nor would the opinions of his strong opponents, but don't you think it's reasonable that at least some members of the public would quite reasonably want to know the information to decide to who they'd prefer giving access to the most closely guarded national secrets and huge influence over the tax code? 
"The issue I have with this is that the general public is not educated enough to make such a determination." Frankly, I disagree. Not every individual member of the public is educated enough but as a whole the public body is.

Comment: However, based on the limited information about them which has come out, I do agree that Trump releasing his tax returns would probably not be in his best interests personally, and I think that's why he hasn't done so.

Comment: @WBT 'Not every individual member of the public is educated enough but as a whole the public body is.' - Have to strongly disagree with you there, individuals may be intelligent or educated but people as a group are stupid.

Comment: @WBT '...members of the public would quite reasonably want to know the information to decide to who they'd prefer giving access to the most closely guarded national secrets and huge influence over the tax code...' - They might want to know, but its none of their business. Once again, we have a government agency which audits and enforces tax law, that is not the job of the general public.
We can assume Trump hasn't done anything illegal otherwise the IRS would of made a move by now. So, if he hasn't done anything illegal, then what would the general public do with his tax info?

Comment: @WBT As I said, if Trump hasn't done anything illegal, then there is NO practical purpose for releasing his tax info to the general public.  I would ask you, if Trump hasn't done anything illegal, then what would YOU do if you were able to view his tax information?

Comment: @NetServOps For the same reason I might want to know if a School Board candidate has kids in the schools they're seeking to administer.  It's useful to know what the individual's personal incentives are to have an idea which direction they might be incentivized to move policy.

Comment: @WBT If you're saying you want to know what business interests Trump has which you think might sway his policy making in favor of those interests, then there is a mountain of publicly available information both on his history of business and where his current business interests are, as there is with ALL people running a business. Viewing his tax returns is not required for this. So we come back to the only reason anyone would want to view his tax returns and that is to determine if he has done anything illegal. Once again, not your job, its the IRS.

Comment: You are certainly right: The leftist's performance during Trump's administration was a concatenation of the theatres. It took Mrs. Clinton about one year to realize, that she is not president, then the outrage at the immigration stop from countries classified by Obama as terror states, then the Russian Collusion based on people doing their diplomatic job, which couldn't come to light before Meghan Kelly interviewed Mr. Putin (well reflecting the effectiveness of Muller & Co. and tons of paper work), timeless: the wall theatre, no Wuhan collusion. -11 votes questions the community title

Comment: ... and it does not seem to end
https://finaltelegraph.com/2022/02/12/breaking-melania-trump-is-being-now-being-investigated-and-the-reason-why-will-boil-your-blood/